Gas Fees is being deducted but not swap is performed (Uniswap v3 router)
Gas Fees is being deducted but not swap is performed (Uniswap v3 router), wrote this code for swap exchange between usdc and dai in node js, the swap function is working but there is no exchange being taken place, althought the gas fees is being deducted
const ethers = require('ethers');
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const ABI = require('./abi.json');
const ERC = require('./ERC20abi.json');
const PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY;

const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider('https://base-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/alcht_ECRFwRe1pH5sKP1FSBGo3SpLFVTXNS');
const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(PRIVATE_KEY, provider);

const routerAddress = "0xE592427A0AEce92De3Edee1F18E0157C05861564";

const routerABI = ABI;

const routerContract = new ethers.Contract(routerAddress, routerABI, wallet);

async function swapTokens(inputToken, outputToken, amountIn, slippage, recipient) {
    const amountInWei = ethers.parseUnits(amountIn, 6); // assuming USDC has 6 decimals
    const slippageTolerance = ethers.parseUnits(slippage, 2);

    const tokenContract = new ethers.Contract(inputToken, ERC, wallet);
    const approveTx = await tokenContract.approve(routerAddress, amountInWei);
    await approveTx.wait();

    const swapParams = {
        tokenIn: inputToken,
        tokenOut: outputToken,
        fee: 3000, 
        recipient: recipient,
        deadline: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 10, // 10 minutes from now
        amountIn: amountInWei,
        amountOutMinimum: 0,
        sqrtPriceLimitX96: 0
    };

    const tx = await routerContract.exactInputSingle(swapParams);
    console.log(`Transaction hash: ${tx.hash}`);
    await tx.wait();
    console.log('Swap complete');
}

async function checkBalance(address,) {
  try {
      // Get the wallet's public address
      const address = wallet.address;

      // Get the balance of the wallet in wei (smallest denomination)
      const balanceWei = await provider.getBalance(address);

      // Convert the balance to Ether (Base chain uses ETH-like denominations)
      const balanceEth = ethers.utils.formatEther(balanceWei);

      console.log(`Balance of ${address}: ${balanceEth} ETH`);
  } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error checking balance:', error);
  }
}

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.post('/swap', async (req, res) => {
    const { inputToken, outputToken, amountIn, slippage, recipient } = req.body;
    try {
        await swapTokens(inputToken, outputToken, amountIn, slippage, recipient);
        res.status(200).send('Swap successful');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).send('Swap failed');
    }
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server running on port 3000');
});

the swap function is working but there is no exchange being taken place, althought the gas fees is being deducted
